# Efficient method to determine which pages of a file are cached

Tags: c, linux

The problem I have in mind is efficiently doing multiple asynchronous random-access reads on a regular file, where the order of the reads does not matter, but I want to start getting data to process as soon as possible. Unless I can afford a thread for each read, it makes sense to start with the reads for sections of the file which are already present in cache, and issue `fadvise` requests for the others in hopes that they'll be available by the time the already-cached ones are read.

One way to determine what parts of a file are already cached is to `mmap` the file, then open `/proc/self/pagemap` and use `readv` on it to get information on the presence of the mapped pages corresponding to the needed regions of the file. The downsides of this method are that it doesn't work (or at least multiple `mmap` and `munmap` steps are needed) if the whole file doesn't fit in virtual address space (highly relevant issue for large files on 32-bit systems), and opening and reading `/proc` files tends to be slow (but I haven't tested for `pagemap` in particular).

Is there any more direct way to get information on cache presence for a file, given the fd? Maybe an `ioctl` of some sort?

Comment: I am not sure if this particular optimization would be worth it. 1. It would mostly be relevant at application start-up - afterwards the behaviour of the cache would depend mostly on what your application does. 2. Getting details on the OS cache and deciding based on them would probably be too expensive. 3. The various prefetching techniques are hit-and-miss anyway. 4. Building your own cache mechanism with higher-level structures (and possibly direct I/O) is generally more efficient.

Comment: Perhaps you could add a few more details on the problem that you are trying to address and your environment? Do you have a single application with few files? Several independent processes with millions of files? Because, quite honestly, trying to second-guess the OS cache is not the way to go in 99.99% of all cases...